# Has R2-D2 ever been inside the Millennium Falcon's cockpit?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

I was perusing some pictures of the Millennium Falcon, especially the cockpit, and it got me wondering how many people we've seen in the cockpit.  As far as I can recall, the list is limited to Han, Chewbacca, Luke, Leia, Obi Wan, C-3PO, Lando, and Nien Nunb.

This led me to the present question:

### In the original trilogy, has R2-D2 ever been seen inside the cockpit of the Millennium Falcon?

As a bonus question, if he hasn't been in the cockpit, do we know why?  I imagine that it might be difficult to get him in and out without assistance.

Comment: I must admit this is a question I had never thought about before.

Comment: Looking at various online cockpit pics from the OT movies, I don't think there is enough space for R2D2 to actually fit in the cockpit, especially with people sitting in the back seats. But, I did find a funny image of [R2D2, C3P0 and BB8 "Taking the Falcon for a Spin"](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-41DuDNTHi2k/VWc146m_XPI/AAAAAAAAPFk/gfiPRwynmTw/s1600/droids%2Bjoyride.jpg)

Comment: I think the best we can get here is there's no shot of him doing so.  The closes he's gotten is the passageway that seems to lead from the cockpit to the central area where the various casts assemble where the holochess board is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not in the original trilogy, anyway.

**ANH** = Han, Chewie, Luke, Ben, Leia

[image]
[image]

ESB = Threepio, Lando

[image]
[image]

RoTJ = Nien Nunb, Blount, Cracken, Unnamed Rebel Navigator

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Given that the stated purpose of astro droids is repair and computation I would say no.

From the [wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Astromech_droid/Canon):

> An astromech droid, also referred to as an astro droid or mech, was a
>   type of droid that served as an automated mechanic on starships. These
>   compact droids used tool-tipped appendages stored in recessed
>   compartments. Many starfighters relied on astromech copilots. Sitting
>   in an astromech socket exposed to space, the droid, in addition to its
>   piloting duties, could calculate hyperspace jumps and perform simple
>   repairs. Most astromechs were only able to communicate in writing,
>   conveyed via another computer system, or through a special code of
>   clicks, bleeps, and similar sounds, known as [Binary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Binary/Canon).

Being unable to communicate directly with anyone else (save C-3PO) and since the cockpit had limited floor space, I think we can logically conclude that there would be no reason for him to ever go in that part of the ship.

Comment: I think the first part of this is probably right - he is never seen there - but I don't know about the reasoning you used.  We see him hanging out, not doing much of anything useful, in several scenes inside the Falcon.  Why wouldn't he want to hang out with the only guy who understands him?  If R2 isn't needed elsewhere, and C-3PO is in the cockpit, wouldn't R2 tend to stick close to his buddy?

Comment: +1 though.  I'm not saying you're wrong, just saying that not being needed in the cockpit doesn't necessarily mean that he wouldn't be there anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the +1. The only thing I could think of was floor space being limited. This shot: http://tinyurl.com/o7swuc4 seems to show the door to the cockpit close behind the chairs that Leia and C-3PO are sitting in.

Comment: Open?  http://www.tradingcarddb.com/Images/Cards/Non-Sport/72989/72989-5257632Fr.jpg

Comment: I didn't mean "close" as in it had closed behind them. I meant proximity.

Comment: OOOOH, OK.  Yeah, there might not be enough room for R2-D2.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the amount of time that the rebel alliance had possession of the Falcon (by proxy through Han) and how often it was used, R2D2 must have at some point been in the cockpit. However I do not know of any pictures nor canon or even non-canon evidence of this.

Comment: Why would an astromech droid need to be in the cockpit for any reason?

Comment: He wouldnt, it's just a matter of time being part of the team.

Comment: @BrendanHughes Why would C-3PO need to be there?  He wouldn't.  But he is, and frequently.

Comment: True, but at least he can communicate with other beings. Having hands might also be useful if he was needed to operate anything. 
Granted - R2-D2 could, maybe, plug in directly and operate that way. Although we do know that at least to communicate with the hyper-drive, C-3PO had to go and be physically near it. No such thing as wireless in a galaxy far far away it seems